FieldAnalysis() not working with .tif image
I am trying to analyze a radiochromic film scan using Pylinac but I am getting a bunch of errors.
I first tried this but got the follwing error:
from pylinac import FieldAnalysis, image, FieldProfileAnalysis
fa = FieldAnalysis(img_path)
fa.analyze()

Output:
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_stats_mstats_common.py:154, in linregress(x, y, alternative)
    151     y = np.asarray(y)
    153 if x.size == 0 or y.size == 0:
--> 154     raise ValueError("Inputs must not be empty.")
    156 if np.amax(x) == np.amin(x) and len(x) > 1:
    157     raise ValueError("Cannot calculate a linear regression "
    158                      "if all x values are identical")

ValueError: Inputs must not be empty.


So next, I directly put the image as the argument for FieldAnalysis(), but that didn't work either:
fa = FieldAnalysis(img)
fa.analyze()

Output:
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_polyint.py:126, in _Interpolator1D._set_yi(self, yi, xi, axis)
    124     shape = (1,)
    125 if xi is not None and shape[axis] != len(xi):
--> 126     raise ValueError("x and y arrays must be equal in length along "
    127                      "interpolation axis.")
    129 self._y_axis = (axis % yi.ndim)
    130 self._y_extra_shape = yi.shape[:self._y_axis]+yi.shape[self._y_axis+1:]

ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis.

I resized the image but no luck. What could be the problem?
